# Benchmark data-set for protein-protein interaction network dataset

Tags: cluster-analysis

I want to apply my clustering algorithm to specifically on protein-protein interaction(PPI) network. For that I need a benchmark dataset with the reference, so that I can validate my result. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to read *Evaluation of clustering algorithms for protein-protein interaction networks* by van Brohee and van Helden (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17087821). I think their benchmark data is available, and they do a very good job of avoiding many of the pitfalls that exist when comparing clustering algorithms and/or gold standards.